# How to view an encrypted view or stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am working on a third party database.

When I try to view the definition of a view by right clicking, `CREATE TO` and then to `NEW QUERY EDIT WINDOW`, I am getting an error:

> This property may not exist for this object or may not be retrievable
>   due to insufficient access rights. The text is encrypted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Another third party tool you could use to decrypt encryted objects on the fly is Red Gate's SQL Prompt:
http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/features

Hovering over the stored procedure will then allow you to see the decrypted creation script.

Disclaimers: this tool is commercial (with a 14 day free trial) and I work for Red Gate.

Comment: I installed SQL Prompt. I have a sysadmin role. I still cannot see the decrypted creation script? Is there something special that needs to be configured prior?

Answer (score 21):

I have a fairly detailed description about this problem [here](http://sqlity.net/en/1617/decrypting-encrypted-database-objects/).

In short, the object is not really encrypted, but rather obfuscated. Therefore we can retrieve the original back. The method is a little involved but it consists of these steps:

1. Connect to the instance using the [Dedicated Admin Connection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178068(v=sql.105).aspx)
2. Select the obfuscated code like this:

   ```
   SELECT @secret = imageval
   FROM   sys.sysobjvalues
   WHERE  objid = OBJECT_ID(@object_name);
   ```
3. Replace the object with another one that has the same name same object_id and the same length in bytes (e.g. using `ALTER PROCEDURE`)
4. Get the newly obfuscated code the same way as above
5. XOR the three values together (obfuscated original, replacement and obfuscated replacement)

That will give you the original code. However, as Kin mentioned, there might be support and even legal implications with doing this so be sure to consult your lawyer first.

Answer (score 18):

The module text is encrypted using an **RC4** stream cipher.

The RC4 initialization key is computed from the **SHA-1** hash of:

- The **database family GUID** (from *[sys.database_recovery_status](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms178575.aspx)*)
  Converted from *uniqueidentifier* to *binary(16)*
- The module's **object ID** (from the catalog views)
  Converted from *integer* to little-endian *binary(4)*
- The module's **object sub-ID**
  Converted from *smallint* to little-endian *binary(2)*.

The module's object sub-ID is:

- 1 for an unnumbered stored procedure; or
- The procedure number for a (deprecated) numbered stored procedure; or
- 0 otherwise.

A suitably privileged user can then decrypt the module by:

1. Obtaining the encrypted binary from *sys.sysobjvalues* (using the DAC)
2. Computing the RC4 key as detailed above
3. Running the well-known standard RC4 algorithm on the binary
4. Converting the result from binary to *nvarchar(max)*

More details and a full code implementation in my article:

[The Internals of `WITH ENCRYPTION`](http://sqlperformance.com/2016/05/sql-performance/the-internals-of-with-encryption)

Answer (score 11):

You can connect to SQL Server using the [Dedicated Administrator Connection (DAC)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178068(v=sql.105).aspx) then view the sql text of the stored procedure. Connect to the DAC using:

```
admin:Your_Servername
```

You can find the full steps needed in [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670636/how-to-decrypt-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-2008/7671944#7671944) by [Martin Smith](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3690/martin-smith).

Another alternative is to use some third party scripts as mentioned in [Decrypting encrypted stored procedures, views, functions in SQL Server 2005, 2008, & R2](http://sqljunkieshare.com/2012/03/07/decrypting-encrypted-stored-procedures-views-functions-in-sql-server-20052008-r2/)

**As a side note** - if it is a third party database and if you do it on prod, will the vendor support it? There may be a good reason to encrypt the SPs or views. It's probably better to take a backup, and then fiddle with that.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to preview original DDL script or to decrypt an encrypted object, you can check out [ApexSQL Decrypt](https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_decrypt.aspx)

It’s a free standalone tool, with an option to integrate it into SSMS, preview original DDL script.
Also, you can decrypt objects located on multiple servers in one turn. 
One more tool that can help you, is [dbForge SQL Decryptor](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqldecryptor/)

Answer (score 1):

A method I use often for decrypting several stored procedures at a time...

Use RedGate's SQL Compare and compare your database against an empty database (or any database you know will not have the stored procedures).  Create a deploy script and copy into SSMS.  Find and replace **WITH ENCRYPTION** with white space.  Then change the CREATE PROCEDURE to ALTER PROCEDURE.  Run the RedGate script against the original database and you've removed all stored procedure encryption.

I had a database with 400+ stored procedures and while SQL Prompt is handy, it was not worth my time to right click, copy, paste against 400+ stored procedures.  Using RedGate SQL Compare I was able to remove encryption from my 400+ stored procedures in roughly 10 minutes start to finish.