# Generate Schema Only Script from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: schema, scripting

Hi this is the first time that I've encounter this error in generating script for my database, what do you think causes this error? Thanks. Please see image.[image]

Comment: Is dbo.DisposeTemporaryTable encrypted?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error as you are trying to script out `OBJECT` that is encrypted. You should read the error carefully as it is self descriptive :

[image]

There are ways that you can use as described [in my answer - How to view an encrypted view or stored procedure ?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/60130/8783) and [here - Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7671944/1387418).