# How to Decrypt Stored proc in Azure Managed SQL Server

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have created Managed SQL Server in Azure and encrypt some stored procedures. Can any one help me to decrypt the same.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60129/how-to-view-an-encrypted-view-or-stored-procedure. Also, do you mean Managed Instance, Azure SQL Database or a SQL Server on a VM in Azure?

Comment: Yes, Managed Instance.. all third party are not working in cloud..

Comment: Ozar says that you can connect to a managed instance with a DAC (although he doesn't explain how) https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/03/azure-sql-managed-instances-brain-dump-on-cpu-memory-ha-dr-and-backups/.  If so, then this https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2964/encrypting-and-decrypting-sql-server-stored-procedures-views-and-userdefined-functions/ should work.